# operation with pandas date frame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

what I am trying to do in this problem is with the following date frame that I have:

```
product  NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                       
2017-10-21    0.703110   0.518214   0.956835   2.292035   0.179191   0.120000   
2017-10-22    0.421140   0.246904   0.680147   0.830645   0.647059   0.484848   
2017-10-23    0.222753   0.240493   0.298851   0.293651   0.291667   0.205882
```

**If these numbers are higher than 0.5 remains the same and multiply for the correspondent in another date frame (below) but if the values are lower than 0.5 than it shall be subtracted from 1 to the correspondent values above and then also multiply only the correspondent values with the date frame (below).**

This is the dateframe which will be used to do the multiplication process with the filter date frame from above

```
productname  NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                       
2017-10-21       10.61       8.51       1.39       2.26       1.73       1.50   
2017-10-22       18.07      12.92       2.72       7.44       2.04       1.32   
2017-10-23       10.46       9.73       0.87       1.26       0.72       0.68
```

I am sure there is an easy way to do this in python which I unhappily did not figure out yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is this correspondent dataframe you speak of?

Comment: Could you explain how you ended up in the output dataframe? Or are they the two dataframes and you havent put output dataframe here?

Comment: english mistake @coldspeed sorry

Comment: The second is not your output dataframe?

Comment: @Bharath I am trying to find filtering the first one and multiplying the second one how would be the output.

Comment: @MayEmanuel Please confirm if you want 1 added to `df1` or `df2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're looking for `np.where`:

```
np.where(df1 < 0.5, df2 + 1, df2) * df1

            NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
2017-10-21   7.459997   4.410001   1.330001   5.179999   0.489191   0.300000
2017-10-22   8.031140   3.436904   1.850000   6.179999   1.320000   1.124847
2017-10-23   2.552749   2.580490   0.558851   0.663651   0.501667   0.345882
```

Comment: Oh no this simple.  Again I thought too much maybe

Comment: @Bharath Can confirm second method's answer is identical to your answer.

Comment: @coldspeed something wrong with np here it will generate an array and not a new date frame right?

Comment: @MayEmanuel For me, with the latest versions of pandas and numpy it works nicely and returns a dataframe.

Comment: @coldspeed this is the best answer and also it will help me in other cases! It works just great!!!

Comment: @MayEmanuel No problem, don't forget to vote on it too. Also, did you want the first one or the second one? (asking so I can remove the one you don't need)

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.where` to replace the values, concat and multiply similar columns by grouping them.

```
ndf = df2.where(df1>0.5,df2+1)

x = pd.concat([ndf,df1],1)
new = x.groupby(by=x.columns,axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:,0]*x.iloc[:,1])
```

```
       NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-10-21   7.459997   4.410001   1.330001   5.179999   0.489191   0.300000
2017-10-22   8.031140   3.436904   1.850000   6.179999   1.320000   1.124847
2017-10-23   2.552749   2.580490   0.558851   0.663651   0.501667   0.345882
```

Comment: I think it's like this: if `df < 0.5`, you increment `df2`.

Comment: Yeah I increment the current df's values but you increment the second df's value mine is similar to `np.where(df1 < 0.5, df1 + 1, df1)` not df2. Shld see what Op expected

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: @coldspeed but this modifies the siye of my dateframe. How could I add a new row in the end so they would have the same size?